# Fetch data and return result to dynamic created element

Tags: javascript, php

I have created php form as be image onchange select stock to display other cell.

[image]

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <th style="width:10px">#</th><th style="width:300px">Name</th><th>Stock</th><th>Qty</th><th>Qty</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <TD style="width:10px"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" id="icode" name="icode[]" onchange="get_stock(this.parentElement.parentElement)">
            <?php
            $sql_br="select * from jsl_store.item_master order by itemname";
            $sql_br_r = oci_parse($con, $sql_br);
            oci_execute($sql_br_r);
            while (oci_fetch($sql_br_r)) {
            ?>
                <option value=<?php echo oci_result($sql_br_r,1); ?>><?php echo oci_result($sql_br_r,2); ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="istock" name="istock[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="iqty"></td>
        <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="rqty"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
function get_stock(thisRow) {
    var x=thisRow.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'itemstock.php?u=1&itemcode=' + x,
        success: function(data) {
            $("[name='istock[]']").val(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome. "_php form as be image onchange select stock to display other cell_" What does that mean?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please add more details.

Comment: If i select name, stock has to display in the same row but it display all rows the same stock as see in image

Comment: When I select the material name from list, the stock of that material has to display in that row.